# Error plotting 3D function

Tags: matlab

Im trying to plot a 3D function with Matlab, my script contains the following :

```
function f=Untitled(s1 ,s2 , s3)
    s =[s1 s2 s3];
    f= 0.0663 + 0.2099245 *(s(1)^2+s(2)^2+s(3)^2);
endfunction

xdata = linspace(36,36,36);
ydata = linspace(36,36,36);
zdata = linspace(36,36,36);
contour( xdata , ydata , zdata , [1 36 72 110])
```

I got the following error:

> Error in ====> Untitled at 2
>   s=[s1 s2 s3]

I'm newest in Matlab, can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You also need to mention what actually the error is. Also add the function call statement

Answer (score 0):

**There are many issues in your code:**

- `s = [s1 s2 s3];`

  This concatenates `s1` `s2` and `s3` *horizontally* to variable `s`

  To do that, *"the number of rows in each variable should be same"*. That is    the cause of your error.

  You need to check the dimensions of the variable you passed to the
  function `untitled`
- `endfunction` is `Octave` syntax. You just need to use `end` for
  `Matlab`
- Then you are using `s(1)`, `s(2)`, `s(3)` separately inside your
  function.

  Then why did you cat them? you could have used the corresponding
  variables itself like this:

  ```
  f= 0.0663 + 0.2099245 *(s1^2+s2^2+s3^2);
  ```
- Then you are using `linspace`(I don't know what you actually intend to do with `linspace`) for replicating values. Although this
  doesn't pose any issues, there is a separate built-in function for
  that called
  [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

  You could use it like this: `repmat(36,[1,36])`

**Note:** Also name your function to any other name for good practice

Comment: s1,s2 and s3, are just simple variables I don't understand what do you mean by :"the number of rows in each variable should be same". @Santhan Salai

Comment: @SaraSara simple scalar? that is strange. why are you concatenating them anyways.. you haven't used them in your code. Also add the function call statement to your question